# Merge and sum Pandas Pivot Table

Tags: pandas

I have this code to merget pivot tables, but falling but grouping by 'index'.
How groupby can be done by index ?

```
pivot1= pd.DataFrame.pivot_table(df, values='ITEM_COUNT', index=['I_DATE'],  columns=['SMALL_AREA_NAME'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
df_list= [pivot1, pivot2]
df2= pd.concat(df_list).groupby(by=['index']).sum()
```

Error when merging on index

```
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\Anaconda27\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'index'
```

Comment: IIUC try `df2= pd.concat(df_list).groupby(level='index').sum()`, `by` looks for column labels but `index` is now your index so you need to pass a `level` arg

Comment: ValueError: level name index is not the name of the index

Comment: what does `pd.concat(df_list).info()` show?

Comment: try this `pd.concat(df_list).groupby(by=['I_DATE']).sum()`

Comment: 'I_DATE' not found....

Answer (score -1):

One Solution found, for the record :

```
pd.concat(df_list).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Just wondering if this is the only solution....